# Purchases on fortnite mobile not transferring to PS4

Tags: ps4, fortnite-battle-royale

I bought a lot of vbucks on mobile. I even bought the battle pass and a few skins and dances (on mobile). I also have a ps4 account which has the exact same username as my mobile. I linked my account to my ps4 and everything, but none of my purchases are showing up on my ps4, not even my progress. I've tried re-installing fortnite (on both platforms) as well as tried unlinking and linking it back on Ps4. Nothing is working. My skins and emotes on mobile, are not showing up on my Playstation. I've run out of ideas, help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! If you haven't already, please take the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help centre](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help)

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the [steps here?](https://epicgames.helpshift.com/a/fortnite/?amp%3Bf=how-do-i-connect-my-psn-account-to-my-epic-account&s=fortnite-ps4-support&f=how-do-i-connect-my-psn-account-to-my-epic-account)

> To connect your PSN account to your Epic account, please refer to the below processes:
>
> 1. If you have not yet played Fortnite on PlayStation 4:
> 2. Click the silhouette icon in the upper right corner of the Epic website to open the sign-in screen.​
> 3. Sign in with your Epic account credentials.
> 4. Hover over your display name beside the silhouette icon and select ACCOUNT.
> 5. Click CONNECTED ACCOUNTS.
> 6. Click CONNECT under PLAYSTATION NETWORK.
> 7. When prompted, sign into your PSN account.
> 8. You will be asked to confirm that you want to connect your Epic and PSN accounts. Click Continue.
>
> If you have played Fortnite on PlayStation 4 already:
>
> 1. In the upper right corner of the Epic website, click the silhouette icon to to open the sign-in screen.
>      ​
> 2. Click the PlayStation icon on the sign-in screen.
>      ​
> 3. A Sony sign-in page will open in a new window.  Sign into your PSN account.
> 4. When prompted, register with Epic by adding an email address and display name to your Epic account.
>
> Note: You will need to register with an email address and display name that is not already in use on an existing Epic account.

Afterwards, make sure your Mobile account is linked to your Epic account.

If the above doesn't help your situation, your best bet is to contact Epic Games Support. You can contact them here: https://epicgames.helpshift.com/a/fortnite/?contact=1

Cheers!